# Check "type" of ERC20 token

Tags: solidity

I am deploying a contract that accepts USDT, and returns a ERC20 token in return. Something like this:

```
  function deposit(uint256 amount) override external payable {
    IERC20 usdt = IERC20(msg.sender);
    MyToken token = new MyToken();

    // Transfer amount USDT tokens from msg.sender to contract
    usdt.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);

    // Send amount tokens to msg.sender
    token.transfer(msg.sender, amount);
  }
```

What I would like to know is how to determine that the ERC20 token being passed to my contract is USDT? I suppose I could check the name and symbol, but that sounds like a hack (and string comparison will probably cost gas). Any other suggestions?

Comment: bro,i don't really even understand this token ting.woke up and was seeing bp2 and BP 20 on my crypto wallet gee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mistake in your code. You never pass the address of `msg.sender` to an interface constructor.

The solution to always interact with USDT is to store [its address](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7) as a constant.

```
address public constant USDT_ADDRESS = 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7;

function deposit(uint256 amount) override external payable {
    IERC20 usdt = IERC20(USDT_ADDRESS);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. I guess you could just add a require to ensure the ERC20 token you get has the same address as the constant USDT_ADRESS? Quick question from a newbie: How do you find the USDT contract address?

Comment: Not sure what you need that "require" for, given that the address is in storage, and is a constant.

Comment: You can use a blockchain explorer like [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io) to find contract addresses.

Comment: Perhaps I was not explicit what I wanted to do with the require. The require would ensure that there is enough (in this case) USDT in the account. So something like this: `require(usdt.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= amount, "Account does not have enough USDT tokens");`

Comment: You don't have to do that. All genuine ERC-20 implementations make that check for you.

Comment: Paul, could you suggest how the code you suggested could be unit tested?

Comment: That's a very broad question, which I can't answer succinctly here. I suggest you go through the [Hardhat tutorial](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/).